# Tech Specs of Built-in iSight Camera of MacBook (13-inch, Aluminum, Late 2008)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, camera, webcam

What are the tech specs of the Built-in iSight Camera of the MacBook (13-inch, Aluminum, Late 2008)?

Especially: What is the focal length?

Does anybody happen to now, if there is something online, where all the technical specifications of my camera are listed?

EDIT: I wrote a program which detects markers of a certain size. After detection I need to calculate the 3D coordinates of those markers, therefore I need the focal length of my camera as this is an input value of the program.

Comment: don't make this one of those "mushroom" questions! keep in the dark and feed with dung", maybe if you explain what for, why, ect... someone could take the time to find the info for you.

Comment: and the iSight camera is a fixed focus camera which means there is no focal length to detect.

Comment: This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISight) may help.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD: Ok thank you, but my program has the focal length of my camera as input. Any idea what they would like to have then, if there is no focal length? Maybe the code is not so evolved?

Comment: @IconDaemon: Thx, but I've seen that already :D

Answer (score -1):

What is recommended is doing a camera calibration yourself, using OpenCV for instance, to get reliable figures.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

It is not very complicated, just print out the chessboard pattern, tweak the xml file which has input data for information about the test pattern and also the xml for input images(if you plan on using images, instead of live video through your webcam, I recommend the latter) 
Run the sample as it is, following the instructions for keyboard prompts (hold up pattern, press 'g' to start calibration once you see detected lines, esc to exit).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question to me.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if the answer sounds irrelevant. The above advice was given because the OP made an edit that said he needs the values for a 3d vision application,(which he might be doing using OpenCV), and in my experience, a camera calibration is all that is required for that, as is also done, for example, before doing 3D reconstruction using SFM in OpenCV. These programs that need focal length as input usually ignore the fixed focus lens part, for reasons I don't know, and still ask for an estimate of focal length, and results from a camera calibration usually give good results when supplied.